# MonoTouch: UITableViewController,NavigationController is null after NavigationController.PushViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I'm building a window-based (all UI programatically wired up, no IB) MonoTouch app using the following strategy:

Pseudo code:

```
 Note: I'm not calling base.ViewDidLoad on any of the ViewDidLoad calls, 
 nor calling any base constructors of any ViewController 
 subclass I've implemented. 

 AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
      FinishedLaunching() 
             window.AddSubView(tabbarController.View)

 TabbarController : UITabbarController
       ViewDidLoad() 
              ViewControllers[0] = myNavigationController

 MyNavigationController : UINavigationController
       ViewDidLoad()
             PushViewController(myTableViewController,false)

 MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
        ViewDidLoad() 
             //Property NavigationController is NULL.
```

According to developer.apple.com, one should create NavigationControllers using a ObjC init method named initWithRootController, but I could not find any MonoTouch equivalent of doing this.

Ref http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html

**Should not MyNavigationControllers PushViewController method autoassign the NavigationController property of the MyTableViewController instance? 
Is there anything I might be missing to get this autowiring going?**

Everything else works as expected. Very grateful to the MT team! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create the instance of `myNavigationController` how are you doing so? I believe the C# equivalent for `initWithRootController` is:

```
UINavigationController navController = new UINavigationController(rootViewController);
```

To implement this in your custom `UINavigationController` you would have to create a new constructor along the lines of:

```
MyNavigationController(UIViewController rootViewController)
{
    ViewControllers = new UIViewController[1] { rootViewController };
}
```

This would set the rootViewController for you. You would need to remove the `PushViewController` from the `ViewDidLoad` method. Any subsequent ViewControllers pushed via `PushViewController` will have this `NavigationController` property automatically set for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering! 

So if I understand you correctly, for the autowiring of the NavigationController property of myTableViewController to work, my custom navigationController MUST have it's ViewControllers[0] set? And this is only needed when i subclass UINavigationController (which seems to be against what Apple recommend, ref http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

"This class is not intended for subclassing. "

Will try this out tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, as you're not subclassing UINavigationController then all you will need to do is instantiate as `UINavigationController navController = new UINavigationController(rootViewController);`